# VB.NET application setup with LocalDb on client pc

Tags: vb.net, localdb

I'm now finished with my application and am going to deploy it on the client PC.  My database is a localDb.  What do I need to install in the client PC in order to make it work on the there?  The client PC is 32-bit and x64 based processor.  I've read that I need to have LocalDb, NET Framework, and Management Studio installed there to work?

Comment: You don't need Management Studio because the user doesn't need to manage the database. The other two are required.

Comment: Well, I'm fairly new to doing this and am still learning as I go along so yeah.  I'm sorry. @muffi

Comment: @jmcilhinney I see.  Okay.  Thank you!

Comment: For clarification, LocalDB is a very basic SQL Server instance. Without a SQL Server instance installed, your SQL Server data file is useless because there's nothing to actually execute queries against the data it contains.  The .NET Framework is the class library that your app relies on, e.g. it contains the definition of the `String` class, and it's also a number of essential tools, e.g. the JIT compiler that converts your .NET EXE file into native code that can be run on the local machine.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you for making it clear for me.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I would like to ask if SQL Server isn't necessary to be installed in the client PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Depending on the client PC operation system version, and the .NET version that you target, you may not need to install .NET Framework (Windows 8 and later comes with .NET 4.5)

2: You should not install LocalDB, but the smallest SQL Express package. It contains command line tools to interact with the database.
Go to: https://www.microsoft.com/da-dk/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express 
Run the installer, and select "Download media" - "Express Core" to download the SQL Server Express installer